# simple_form でラベルと input を横並びにしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
= simple_form_for @memo, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  = f.input :count
```

という number_field があって
これをラベルと入力欄を横並びにして
さらに入力欄の右に単位をつけたいです

simple_form を使わずに label, number_field を使ってかく以外にないですか？

simple_form に任せたほうが統一感のあるデザインになるのですが
入力が短いのに画面いっぱい使うレイアウトだけはカスタマイズしたいです

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f.label 
f.text_field
でかくと緑にならなくてバリデーション失敗時のエラーの表示もかわっちゃうので

```
.row
  = f.label class: 'col-3'
  = f.input :count, label: false, input_html: {class: 'form-control-sm col-3'}
  %span.col-1= t '.times'
```

で label: false で input だけにしてラベルは別にくっつけることにしました